# Truth in advertising; Fargo claims of being a true story

Tags: fargo-tv

Isn't it against the law to blatantly lie to the viewing public?  If the TV series [Fargo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2802850/) is not true then why do they say it is?

Comment: Questions about the law are best answered by lawyers

Comment: Lying in general isn't against the law in most/all territories, and Fargo isn't an advertisement.  Your point is?

Comment: Is this question really a duplicate? The one that is linked is addressing whether or not the events really are true or not. This question asks how they are able to claim it is true when it is not.

Comment: @sanpaco totally agree. does not make sense, and this question deserves an answer!

Answer (score 5):

**No.** It is **not** against the law. Otherwise the Coen brothers (and many others) would be in jail.

Also, to just name **one** other occurrence of the "true story" bit before a movie, *eleven years earlier*, 1985's *[Return of the Living Dead](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0089907/)* also claimed to be based on a true story. The trailer is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wylpeAXYcBQ), and the movie (for however long it lasts), is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mO9ZKzF9EmM). **EDIT :** The YouTube version doesn't have the screenshot I was talking about, so I captured it from my DVD copy:

[image]

And that movie is about lucid, fast zombies.

Movies are not encyclopedias. They are not facts overseen by a committee to ensure accuracy. Even docudramas and biopics are not 100% accurate.

**Sound advice:**

> If you're wondering how he eats and breathes
>
> And other science facts,
>
> Just repeat to yourself  "It's just a show,
>
> I should really just relax
>
> For Mystery Science Theater 3000."